# Math with types

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do the following in typescript without external tooling?

```js
type one = 1;
type two = 2;
type three = one + two; // Doesn't work
type negOne = one - two;
type oneHalf = one / two;
type four = two * two;
type zero = four % two;
```

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: Sort of, but practically, no. See: https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f. And you're probably limited to addition/subtraction of small integers, maybe multiplication, division would be impressive.

Comment: Are there any plans to add this as a future feature?

Comment: I don't think so. Here's a link to a relevant [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) and [another](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223) and [another](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15645). Doesn't look like this is a priority. It's really hard to get this right.